# Trigger Airflow DAG based on file change

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to write a pipeline where I wait for JSON files in a directory to be modified, then I have to run another DAG.
I have tried this code using the `TriggerDagRunOperator` to run the other DAG and `watchdog` to monitor the files, but the `hello_world_dag` DAG doesn't run when I edit the file being watched:
PS: The code is inspired from [this one](https://gist.github.com/wandermonk/68c214446c585d50228a8ad64b9589b7)

`helper_dag`:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
from datetime import datetime

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="helper_dag",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 5, 28),
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval="@once",
)

trigger_other_dag = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="trigger_dagrun",
    trigger_dag_id="hello_world_dag",
    dag=dag,
    retries=0,
)

class Handler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        trigger_other_dag 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_event_handler = Handler(
        patterns=["*.json"],
        ignore_patterns=None,
        ignore_directories=False,
        case_sensitive=True,
    )
    my_observer = Observer()
    my_observer.schedule(
        event_handler=my_event_handler, path="/home/airflowsrv/airflow/", recursive=True
    )
    my_observer.start()
```

`hello_world_dag` (the main pipeline I want to run when the JSON file is changed):

```py
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator


def print_hello():
    return str(datetime.now())


dag = DAG(
    "hello_world_dag",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 5, 28),
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval=None,
)

hello_operator = PythonOperator(task_id="hello_task", python_callable=print_hello, dag=dag)
hello_operator
```

Comment: The hello_world_dag is getting triggered for me using the same code. Could you share the log of the helper_dag ?

Comment: thanks @adhithiyan for your time, I dont get any runs in the helper_dag when I change the json files in the monitored directory, but the DAGs run one time when I activate them in the UI. Heres the log for the helper DAG a you asked: [Link](https://gist.github.com/Aymane11/2f54ee4cbaf0b2ddaab9656e58e3cb6a)

Comment: Hi @enamya. I misunderstood the issue. As you said, the changes in json file are not triggering the helper_dag.  I do not think airflow would understand the dependency set through event handler. Also, your main script ends after starting the observer thread so the observer thread will also end.  The main thread needs to be alive as shown in the quick start example: https://python-watchdog.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html  I would suggest keeping the watchdog script outside airflow and triggering the DAG from that script.

Comment: Even then, If the file gets modified very frequently, you may end up triggering multiple DagRun simultaneously. I would like to point out that airflow is not suited for streaming jobs.